# How trigger a function when scroll reaches to the bottom

Tags: angularjs

How can I trigger a function when the scroll reaches the bottom of a `<md-contend>`? does angularjs have an own directive for that? functions from scope do not work in HTML `onscroll` Event Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow was my solution but I need to know if there is another way to do it or if angularjs has its own directive.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myComponentId')).bind('scroll', function(){
    let offsetHeight = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#myComponentId' ) )[0].offsetHeight,
    scrollTop = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#myComponentId' ) )[0].scrollTop,
    scrollHeight = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#myComponentId' ) )[0].scrollHeight,
    toBottom = offsetHeight + scrollTop;

    if(toBottom >= scrollHeight) {
      $scope.reachedTheBottom = false;
      $scope.$apply();
    }
    else {
      $scope.reachedTheBottom = true;
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  })
```

Comment: To create a directive, read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)